# What characters need to be escaped when using E'xxx' syntax on Postgres

Tags: postgresql

When inserting data on a Postgres database, I make extensive use of escaped strings as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).

Sometimes I execute a batch of inserts surrounded by `$$`. On the `VALUES` clause, I use `E'xxx'` syntax on every string value. Today I had a hard time debugging a batch that reported a non closing `$$`. Long story short, the culprit where braces (`{}`) in one string value.

For example:

```
DO $$
insert ( ... ) values ( ... );
insert ( ... ) values ( ... );
insert ( ... ) values ( ..., E'123, Belevue st (near Top Hat bar)' ... );
insert ( ... ) values ( ..., E'456, Not So Belevue st {just after the gas shop}', ... );
$$;
```

The presence of parentesis is not a problem, but when there are braces, a error indicating the `$$` string as not closed is issued.

Escaping `{` with `\x7B` and `}` with `\x7D` solved the problem. But I wonder: would be any other character that is mandatory to be escaped the same way? The on-line documentaion fails to describe that.

Does Postgres publishes a BNF or a more formal documentation on that subject?

Comment: Your title says E'xxx' style, while your body says $$ style.  Those are mutually exclusive.  Can you give a clearer example of what you are doing?

Comment: Fair. Just added an example to clarify.

Comment: If I supply the missing BEGIN and END to your DO block and fill in the ellipses, this works for me when entered into `psql`.  As Laurenz suggest, maybe your client program is being overly/underly clever?

Comment: Code is writen in Delphi using FireDAC library, but the same error was reported when executing the same batch on DBeaver, a java program.

Comment: I don't know about Delphi, but when I put that into a text file and open and execute it with DBeaver it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

No character needs to be escaped in a dollar quoted string:

```
SELECT $$braces { are no problem }$$;

         ?column?          
---------------------------
 braces { are no problem }
(1 row)
```

It must be something in your client code (you didn't specify the programming language you are using) that has a problem with these characters.